# Android:best practice to implement LocationManager

Tags: android, android-service, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am making an application sends the coordinates of latitude and longitude, so I'm extending a service  and implemented LocationManager.
This is part of my code:

```html
public class LocationServiceTracking extends Service implements LocationListener{
....
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (isGPSEnabled && provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(3000, 0, criteria, this, null);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                } catch (SecurityException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                    Crashlytics.logException(se);
                }
            }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

My question is ¿What would be the best practice to do this if you do it in `onCreate ()` as is now or change it to `onStartCommand ()`?

Answer (score 1):

Read about FusedLocationProvider api for android.

It will handle most of the complications.If gps is not enabled it takes the co-ordinates from the network provider etc.
Read it here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Answer (score 1):

Use Fused location api for brevity.

About your question - it's better to do it in `onCreate()` because `onStartCommand()` will be called as many times as you triggered start service and onCreate only when service is actually created.

[Calling start service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

[Service lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

***It should be in `onStartCommand()`***

> Reason : `onCreate()` will be called whenever the service is created
>   But `onStartCommand()` will be called when you manually start the
>   service by calling `obj.startService()`.

So if you are putting that code in `onCreate()` you will start receiving updates BEFORE you start the service which is not a good practice. The code written in `Service` should be enabled only when it is **started** or **bound**.

For e.g.

```
MyService serviceObj = new MyService(); // this will call onCreate().

serviceObj.startService(); // this will call `onStartCommand()`.

serviceObj.bindService(); // this will call onBind(). (Not your case).
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a field in your class called `mGoogleApiClient`.

Then in `onCreate` do this:

```
// Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

When the class loads and stops, handle the lifecycle of this field:

```
public void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

public void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Now implement the folliwing interfaces:

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

and add their methods:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Maps API::onConnected");
    //For Marshmallow 6.0, make sure to check Permissions
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Maps API::onConnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Maps API::onConnectionFailed");
}
```